# Passing related objects in tests

Tags: unit-test, master-detail

I have the following visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Whatever__c" extensions="WhateverExt" action="{!autoRun}">
   <apex:form >
     <apex:outputField value="{!Whatever__c.A}" rendered="false"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!Whatever__c.Foo__r.Bar__c}" rendered="false"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

With the following extension:

```
public class WhateverExt{

  private final Whatever__c t;

  public WhateverExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    this.t = (Whatever__c)stdController.getRecord();
  }

  public PageReference autoRun() {

    OtherClass.OtherMethod(t.Foo__r);
    ...
  }
}
```

My issue is that when I'm testing this page, the `OtherClass.OtherMethod` receives a null pointer. However when doing it for real, it works.

```
global class OtherClass{
  public static void OtherMethod(Foo__c f){
     ...
  }
}
```

My test class is the following:

```
@isTest
public class WhateverExt_Test{

  static PageReference pref;
  static WhateverExt ext;

  static testMethod void test_me(){

    Foo__c f = new Foo__c(Bar__c = '1234');
    insert f;

    Whatever__c t = new Whatever__c(A = '1234', Foo__c = f.Id);
    insert t;

    pref = Page.Whatever;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

    ApexPages.StandardController con = new ApexPages.StandardController(t);
    ext = new WhateverExt(con);

    PageReference savePageRef = ext.autoRun();

    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: You mean `t.Foo__r` is null not that `t` is null when you run your test right?

Comment: @KeithC yep, I seem to receive a null object only when running the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal environment, the platform discovers the fields to include in the query from the page so the presence of `Whatever__c.Foo__r.Bar__c` causes the parent `Foo__c` object to be queried (to obtain its `Bar__c` field) in addition to the `Whatever__c` object. The framework apparently queries both objects in a single query so the relationship field `Foo__r` that your logic relies on is non-null.

But it appears that when you use the [StandardController(SObject)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_constructors.htm) in a test, you are left with the responsibility for the query part of the job. The `Whatever__c` object you pass in has a null `Foo__r` because relationship fields are not automatically populated on inserts.

So one way to fix this is to re-query the two objects together:

```
Whatever__c tt = [select A, Foo__r.Bar__c from Whatever where Id = :t.Id];
```

and pass this object reference into the StandardController(SObject) constructor.

I think that it is also possible to set fields like `Foo__r` so adding this line:

```
t.Foo__r = f;
```

before the constructor is invoked should also work.

Comment: Yup, just tested it out adding this line worked "Whatever__c tt = [select A, Foo__r.Bar__c from Whatever where Id = :t.Id];" whereas mine did not!